# Create a tiny DSL looking function

Tags: scala, slick

I seem to be doing following everywhere in service APIs to create `Slick` transactions.

```
 db.withTransaction{ implicit session =>
  .....
 }
```

Want to create something more DSL looking snippet instead of doing `db.withTransaction` everywhere.

I came up with below

```
def executeInSlickTransaction[T](body: => T) = {
val db = DataSource.getDb
  db.withTransaction{ implicit session =>
    body
  }

 }
```

So now I can call

```
 executeInSlickTransaction{
 ....
 }
```

but then I need `implicit session` as well in `executeInSlickTransaction` e.g. something like

`executeInSlickTransaction{ implicit session => ...}` because `session` implicit is required for DAO calls (made from within `executeInSlickTransaction` block) which expect it.

Is there a way to get `implicit session` back from `executeInSlickTransaction` ?

Comment: correct signature of your method should be `def executeInSlickTransaction[T](body: (Session) => T)` and call `body(session)`. then you will be able to make `Session` implicit in `body` function: `executeInSlickTransaction { implicit session => ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

val db you can store somewhere else. It's just configuration.

You cannot get rid of the implicit keyword if you want to pass around the session implicitly. But you don't have to. If you just execute a single query (or a single function session => results) you can just do something like this:

```
import db.withTransaction
```

Slick 2.0:

```
withTransaction{ someQuery.list()(_) }
```

Slick 2.1:

```
withTransaction{ someQuery.list(_) }
```

Or shorten the name of the session variable, as it doesn't matter really if its implicit:

```
withTransaction{ implicit s =>
    someQuery.list()(_)
}
```

Doesn't seem to me like a "dsl", i.e. just another method could help you. At best you could shorten the name to somethind shorter:

```
import db.{withTransaction => t}

t{ implicit s => q.list }
```

If you are new to Scala and don't understand some concept used here, they should be explained in about every Scala book, but of course there is lots of things at the same time when you are new.